# Trouble Deploying VPC with Subnets with CDK and Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a VPC with subnets for a project, yet I am running into an issue where CDK seems to make two subnets with the same CIDR block when synthesizing the code into a CloudFormation template, even though I only use a CIDR block once per subnet declaration. This causes deployment to fail since CIDR blocks conflict with each other when creating the subnets. Here is the code for defining the stack:

```
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2

class CdkWorkshop3Stack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # The code that defines your stack goes here

        # instantiate VPC with dns support and hostname enabled and cidr block at 10.0.0.0/24
        vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "vpc-cf",
                      cidr="10.0.0.0/24",
                      enable_dns_support=True,
                      enable_dns_hostnames=True
                      )

        # instantiate internet gateway and attach VPC with internet gateway
        igw = ec2.CfnInternetGateway(self, "igw")
        igw_attach = ec2.CfnVPCGatewayAttachment(
            self, "igw_attach", vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id, internet_gateway_id=igw.attr_internet_gateway_id)

        # instantiate elastic IP with VPC domin
        eip = ec2.CfnEIP(self, "eip", domain="VPC")

        # instantiate public and private subnets and use first availability zone
        pub_subnetA = ec2.Subnet(
            self, "public-subnetA", availability_zone=super().availability_zones[0], cidr_block="10.0.0.0/26", vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id, map_public_ip_on_launch=True)
        pub_subnetB = ec2.Subnet(
            self, "public-subnetB", availability_zone=super().availability_zones[0], cidr_block="10.0.0.64/26", vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id, map_public_ip_on_launch=True)
        pri_subnetA = ec2.Subnet(
            self, "private-subnetA", availability_zone=super().availability_zones[0], cidr_block="10.0.0.128/26", vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id, map_public_ip_on_launch=False)
        pri_subnetB = ec2.Subnet(
            self, "private-subnetB", availability_zone=super().availability_zones[0], cidr_block="10.0.0.192/26", vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id, map_public_ip_on_launch=False)

        # instantiate NAT gateway
        nat_gateway = ec2.CfnNatGateway(
            self, "nat_gateway", allocation_id=eip.attr_allocation_id, subnet_id=pub_subnetA.subnet_vpc_id)

        # instantiate routing tables
        pub_route_table = ec2.CfnRouteTable(
            self, "pub_route_table", vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id)
        pri_route_table = ec2.CfnRouteTable(
            self, "pri_route_table", vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id)

        # instantiate public and private routes
        pub_route = ec2.CfnRoute(self, "pub_route", route_table_id=pub_route_table.attr_route_table_id,
                                 destination_cidr_block="0.0.0.0/0", gateway_id=igw.attr_internet_gateway_id)
        pri_route = ec2.CfnRoute(self, "pri_route", route_table_id=pri_route_table.attr_route_table_id,
                                 destination_cidr_block="0.0.0.0/0", nat_gateway_id=nat_gateway.ref)

        # instantiate subnet route table associations
        pub_subnetA_route_table_association = ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
            self, "pub_subnetA_route_table_association", route_table_id=pub_route_table.attr_route_table_id, subnet_id=pub_subnetA.subnet_vpc_id)
        pub_subnetB_route_table_association = ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
            self, "pub_subnetB_route_table_association", route_table_id=pub_route_table.attr_route_table_id, subnet_id=pub_subnetB.subnet_vpc_id)
        pri_subnetA_route_table_association = ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
            self, "pri_subnetA_route_table_association", route_table_id=pri_route_table.attr_route_table_id, subnet_id=pri_subnetA.subnet_vpc_id)
        pri_subnetB_route_table_association = ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
            self, "pri_subnetB_route_table_association", route_table_id=pri_route_table.attr_route_table_id, subnet_id=pri_subnetB.subnet_vpc_id)

        security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, "security_group", vpc=vpc)
        security_group.add_ingress_rule(
            ec2.Peer.ipv4("0.0.0.0/0"), ec2.Port.tcp(22))

        ec2_instance = ec2.Instance(self, "EC2", instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO), machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux(),
                                    key_name="RandomKeyName", security_group=security_group, vpc=vpc, vpc_subnets=pri_subnetA)
```

I do not know how to solve this issue, since clearly it should only use those CIDR blocks once. But it doesn't.

EDIT: I am now including a [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mmkthecoolest/SWEN-614-Grad-Project/main/cdk.out/CdkWorkshop3Stack.template.json) to the CloudFormation template output in response to a comment. I have noticed that this conflict issue only seems to occur with public_subnetA and private_subnetA. I still do not understand why this is happening.

EDIT 2: I tried following maafk's suggestion and reduced my code to the following. I want to keep the 2 public and private subnet configuration, but now I can't connect to my EC2 instance no matter what I try. Why is something that can be easily achieved in Terraform so needlessly hard to do in AWS CDK, let alone in Python?

```
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2

class HelloCdkStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "vpc-cf",
                      cidr="10.0.0.0/24",
                      enable_dns_support=True,
                      enable_dns_hostnames=True,
                      nat_gateways=1,
                      max_azs=1,
                      subnet_configuration=[ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                          name="public-subnetA",
                          cidr_mask=26,
                          subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
                      ), ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                          name="public-subnetB",
                          cidr_mask=26,
                          subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
                      ), ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                          name="private-subnetA",
                          cidr_mask=26,
                          subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE
                      ), ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                          name="private-subnetB",
                          cidr_mask=26,
                          subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE)]
                      )

        ec2_instance = ec2.Instance(self, "EC2", instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO), machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux(
        ), key_name="KeyPairRandom", vpc=vpc, vpc_subnets=vpc.select_subnets(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC).subnets[0])

        ec2_instance.connections.allow_from_any_ipv4(
            ec2.Port.tcp(22), 'Allow inbound SSH from anywhere')
```

Comment: Your cdk code looks ok. Can you share your CloudFormation template? And which subnets are conflicting?

Comment: @shimo please check my edit. I included a link since SO has a character limit.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a lot more code than is necessary.

Creating a VPC with CDK already takes care of most of this for you

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#vpc)

> A default VPC configuration will create public and private subnets

Here is a more "CDK native way" to write this.

```py
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2

class CdkWorkshop3Stack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "vpc-cf",
            cidr="10.0.0.0/24",
            # dns hostnames and support enabled by default
        )

        ec2_instance = ec2.Instance(self, "EC2", 
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO), machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux(),
            key_name="RandomKeyName", 
            vpc=vpc,
            # PRIVATE subnets are chosen by default
        )
        # Not a great security practice to open ssh to the world, but can do it this way
        ec2_instance.connections.allow_from_any_ipv4(ec2.Port.tcp(22), 'Allow inbound SSH from anywhere')
```

Much less code, and using the "sensible defaults" that come with CDK

Comment: How do I make it choose a public subnet. I think the private subnets default is leaving me unable to connect to my instance via SSH.

Comment: Check out the documentation on the Vpc construct.

Comment: Best option for SSH is to use SSM Session manager (installed by default on Amazon Linux), or to use a bastion host in a public subnet. If you absolutely _must_ create your instance in a public subnet, you can add `vpc_subnets=vpc.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC)` to the `ec2.Instance` parameters